# HTML template not getting rendered on gmail

Tags: html, templates, gmail, jinja2, email-templates

I have written a basic HTML template for a gmail report. The template seems to display 'Highlights' when I open it on the chrome browser but it is not displayed while using the template to send emails.

Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .row::after {
            content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: block;
        }
        hr {
            border: none;
            border-top: 3px solid #333;
            color: #333;
            overflow: visible;
            text-align: center;
            height: 5px;
            width:56%;
        }

        hr:after {
            background: #fff;
            content: 'HIGHLIGHTS';
            padding: 0 4px;
            position: relative;
            top: -13px;
            width:56%;
        }
        html {
            font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
        }

        .table_data,.msg_text{
            margin-top:3%;
            margin-bottom:2%;
            height: 5%;
            width:56%;
        }
        .aside {
            background-color: #33b5e5;
            padding: 15px;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
        }
        .logo{
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 3%;
            margin-bottom: 0%;
            }

        .heading
        {
            font-size: 30px;
            color: blue;
            text-align: center; 
            margin-top:-2.5%; 

        }
        table tr th
        {
            background-color:#8e89895c;
            font-size: 18px;
            height: 40px;
        }
        table tr td
        {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 18px;
            height: 40px;

        }
        /* #current_data table tr:nth-child(even) {background: #cccccc73}
        #current_data table tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
         */


        @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
            /* For mobile phones: */
            [class*="col-"] {
                width: 100%;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
            hr {
            border: none;
            border-top: 3px solid #333;
            color: #333;
            overflow: visible;
            text-align: center;
            height: 5px;
            width:100%;
            }

            hr:after {
                background: #fff;
                content: 'HIGHLIGHTS';
                padding: 0 4px;
                position: relative;
                top: -13px;
                width:100%;

            }
            .table_data, .msg_text{
                table-layout: fixed;
                width:100% !important;
                word-break: break-all;
            }
            .heading
            {
                font-size: 25px;
                color: blue;
               text-align: center;
               margin-top:-2.5%; 

            }

        }

    </style>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 right">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-athena-query-results-388603454435-us-east-1/images/smallinsisivlogo.png" width="auto" height="auto"><br>
            </div>
            <div class="heading">
                <p >Your Daily Digest</p> 
            </div>
            <hr>
            <table align="center" class="top_heading">
                <tr><td><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-athena-query-results-388603454435-us-east-1/images/right.png" width="35px" height="35px"></td><td>{{pass_count}} policies passed</td></tr>
                <tr><td><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-athena-query-results-388603454435-us-east-1/images/wrong.png" width="40px" height="40px"></td><td>{{failed_count}} policies failed</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12" id="current_data">
            <table align="center" class="table_data" border="1" cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="0px" style="border-color:black;border-collapse: inherit;">
               <tr>
                                    <th   style="font-size: 20px;background-color: gray;" >Category</th>
                                    <th   style="font-size: 20px;background-color: gray;" >Description</th>
                                    <th   style="font-size: 20px;background-color: gray;" >Count</th>
                                    <th   style="font-size: 20px;background-color: gray;" >Severity</th>
                                    <th   style="font-size: 20px;background-color: gray;" >Resource Failed</th>
                </tr >
                                        {% for items in Sitem %}
                                            <tr>
                                            <td class = "c1">{{items.category_name}}</td>
                                            <td class = "c2">{{items.description}}</td>
                                            <td class = "c3">{{items.count}}</td>
                                            <td class = "c4">{{items.severity}}</td>
                                            <td class = "c5">{{items.resource}}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>                   
        <table class="msg_text" cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="0px" align="center">        
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;font-size: 12px;"><p>Please visit us on <a .../</a> for more information.This is an auto-mailer.Please do not reply to this mail.<br> For any clarifications and support you can contact:<br>+919620</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>                 
</body>
</html>
```

Here the 'Highlights' line is being displayed but it is missing while using it for the template][1]

This is how it looks on gmail :
[As you can see 'Highlights' is missing and the spacing is off][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon seeing your full code, it seems you are implementing the word `HIGHLIGHTS` in your CSS using a pseudo selector. CSS Pseudo selectors are not supported by Gmail clients.

Please see [Campaign Monitors Email CSS Support](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/selectors/after/) - This gives an overview of which email clients support various CSS.

I would recommend that you manually code in your title of Highlights manually (an example of how I would do it is in the snippet below).

Also be careful using the `cellpadding` attribute on `<table>` tags as it can cause issues in other email clients. I would suggest using a Free Trial on [Emails on Acid](http://emailonacid.com) or [Litmus](https://litmus.com/) so that you can see how your email renders on all email clients.

A useful link from my previous answer:

For more Gmail quirks visit [Email on Acid Gmail Blog Article](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/12_things_you_must_know_when_developing_for_gmail_and_gmail_mobile_apps-2/#gmail_tip5) which gives you a full list of quirks that could be causing your problem.

```html
<table role="presentation" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
 <td height="24" width="40%" valign="top">
  <table role="presentation" align="center" width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td height="11" style="max-height: 11px; font-size: 0px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height: 11px; max-height: 11px; border-bottom: #000000 1px solid;">
     &nbsp;
   </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
 </td>
 <td>
  <table role="presentation" class="inner" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
   <td valign="middle" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:26px; color:#222222; text-align: center;" class="body-text">
    <p style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:26px; color:#000000; font-weight:bold; padding:0; margin:0;" class="body-text">
      Highlights
    </p>
   </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
 </td>
 <td height="24" width="40%" valign="top">
  <table role="presentation" align="center" width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td height="11" style="max-height: 11px; font-size: 0px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height: 11px; max-height: 11px; border-bottom: #000000 1px solid;">
    &nbsp;
   </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've edited my answer with my findings now that you've updated the HTML. Hope it helps

Comment: @Sayo1337 +1 for the answer and I would suggest removing the height (height="24") on the outer columns, might not work the same across all email clients. Since there is text in the middle column, the height of the other two columns should work by itself.